# Connecting Kusto Explorer to Log Analytics

Tags: azure, ssl, tls1.2, azure-data-explorer, azure-log-analytics

I'm trying to connect the Kusto Explorer application to our Log Analytics workspace using the following guide

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/query-monitor-data

and using the following URL to connect:

```
https://ade.loganalytics.io/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourcegroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/<workspace-name>
```

This works when using the Azure Data Explorer web interface, but using this in the Kusto.Explorer applcation, I get this:

```
Connection attempt resulted with the following error:
    Kusto client failed to send a request to the service: 'The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.'.
    Error details:
    DataSource='https://ade.loganalytics.io/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/v1/rest/mgmt',
    DatabaseName='NetDefaultDB',
    ClientRequestId='KD2RunCommand;xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    Timestamp=xxxxxxxxx
```

Some googling indicates that this is an issue with ssl certificates, but I don't see anywhere in the Kusto Explorer application where I can influence that.

Perhaps I'm not understanding the issue? Is this something that needs to be changed on our Log Analytics Workspace?

Comment: Can you send the actual client activity id? This will allow us to look into the logs and investigate.

Comment: @Avnera Oops! Sorry about that! Here you go: ClientRequestId='KD2RunCommand;05f61b0f-9887-4694-96eb-20def992a86f'

Comment: I can't find this in our logs and I can't repro this. From the error it seems that there is a connection issue, I would give it another try and also check that you can use Kusto Explorer to connect to other Kusto clusters such as the "help" (demo) cluster: https://help.kusto.windows.net/

Comment: @Avnera, Thanks for checking! I was able to connect to the demo cluster just fine prior to this. Additionally, I actually got it to work now. I'm not exactly sure what did it, but I noticed that after disconnecting from VPN, I was able to connect to LA and see our data.

Answer (score 0):

Check first that Kusto.Explorer works with cluster 'help' database 'samples', to verify that you are set to query Kusto. After you are done with 'help' should also work with Adxproxy.